# Replace <strong> tag with h2 tag

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to write some BeautifulSoup code which will take each piece of text that is surrounded by  tags and change the  tags to  tags - but, only if it's only a line with no other written/output text.

Is this possible?

[image: Before]

to this

[image: After]

But this will remain unchanged :

[image: Unchanged]

I know the following will work to convert all strongs. How can I get only the important ones?

```
import BeautifulSoup

if __name__ == "__main__":
    data = """
<html>
<h2 class='someclass'>some title</h2>
<ul>
   <li>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit.</li>
   <li>Aliquam tincidunt mauris eu risus.</li>
   <li>Vestibulum auctor dapibus neque.</li>
</ul>
</html>

    """
    soup = BeautifulSoup.BeautifulSoup(data)
    h2 = soup.find('strong')
    h2.name = 'h1'
    print soup
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find all `strong` elements and check the length of the [`.parent`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#parent):

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

data = """
<html>
<p><strong>Like this</strong></p>
<p>Hello, <strong>world</strong>
</html>
"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(data)
for strong in soup.find_all('strong'):
    if len(strong.parent) == 1:
        strong.name = 'h1'
print soup
```

Prints (see the first `strong` tag was replaced, the second was not):

```
<html>
<body>
    <p><h1>Like this</h1></p>
    <p>Hello, <strong>world</strong></p>
</body>
</html>
```

Or, in a more concise form:

```
for strong in soup.find_all('strong', lambda x: x and len(x.parent) == 1):
    strong.name = 'h1'
```

As a side note, you are using [`BeautifulSoup3`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs3/documentation.html) which is *no longer maintained*; consider upgrading to [`BeautifulSoup4`](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/):

```
pip install beautifulsoup4
```

Comment: OP will need bs4 though

Answer (score 0):

erm... this may not be as efficient, but is sure simpler to write:

```
data = data.replace('<p><strong>', '<p><h2>')
data = data.replace('</strong></p>', '</h2></p>')
```

or have I misunderstood something fundamental about str.replace()?

This isn't very sophisticated though, but does the job if the html is consistent

edit: a more sophisticated solution using regular expressions:

```
import re

data = re.sub(r'<[Pp]>[\s]*<[Ss][Tt][Rr][Oo][Nn][Gg]>', '<p><h2>', data)
data = re.sub(r'</[Ss][Tt][Rr][Oo][Nn][Gg]>[\s]*</[Pp]>', '</h2></p>', data)
```